# Calling a method with class name and dot operator

Tags: python, methods

When we define a method inside a class and if we try to access that using class_name.method_name, it shows an error demanding an argument for 'self'. Eg prgm as follows :

```
class a:
    def b(self):
        print('method b')
    def c(self):
        print('method c')
        a.b() #self.b()
d=a()
d.c()
a.c()  #d.c()
```

Here inside the method b as well as outside the class, if I call the method b using the class name a, i.e a.c(), it shows error as follows :

```
TypeError : b() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Can you explain why it demands an argument for 'self', though we need not specify that when we call that using object?

Comment: Inside the method `c`, `a` refers to the class - which means `a.b()` is an attribute access. Attribute access does not pass the `self` argument to method calls like method access does

Comment: The code defines the methods to take a self argument. Why are you confused that they need this argument? The code comments indicate that self.b() was attempted as well — what makes you think that a.b() does the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a method is called using an object, the `self` parameter gets automatically passed as the calling object.

When you're calling it with the `class`, there is no way for python to understand who the calling object is, hence, the `self` parameter remains empty.

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
f.bar()
# or
Foo.bar(f)  # explicitly pass f to the self parameter for it to work
```